# Excel VBA: How to find a certain substring

Tags: vba, excel

In column B, I have data for e.g. hmc1, hmc2, hmc3. I want to find every Column B cell that contains "hmc" and replace its corresponding cell in Column A with "Found".
My code so far works if it matches fully, but not if it matches a substring.

```
        If .Range("B" & r).Value = "hmc " Then
            .Range("A" & r).Value = "Found"
```

---

```
Col A   Col B
Accept  hmc1
123     hmc1
123     hmc2
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
123     hmc3
Accept  hmc3
Accept  hmc3
```

Comment: [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/gg264811.aspx) ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your B column data starts with 2

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(LCase(Range("B" & i).Value), "hmc") Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "Found"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: this is it! Does LCase mean Lower case? How about if Col B, may contain example Hmc, HMC, hmc or 110 Hmc, which i dont care as long as it contains the keyword hmc. will it work? tq

Comment: it will work for HMC1 or Hmc1 or hMc1 etc., it will  converts to lcase and check with lowercase hmc

Comment: i tried it works perfectly. thanks a lot, you are really expert!

Comment: If an answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to that answer.